# Sqlmap dont work over TOR Vidalia in WindowsXP

Tags: windows, tor, sqlmap

```
D:\Python27>python sqlmap\sqlmap.py -u www.mail.ru --tor

    sqlmap/1.0-dev - automatic SQL injection and database takeover tool
    http://sqlmap.org

[!] legal disclaimer: Usage of sqlmap for attacking targets without prior mutual
 consent is illegal. It is the end user's responsibility to obey all applicable
local, state and federal laws. Developers assume no liability and are not respon
sible for any misuse or damage caused by this program

[*] starting at 22:28:49

[22:28:49] [WARNING] increasing default value for option '--time-sec' to 10 beca
use switch '--tor' was provided
[22:28:49] [INFO] setting Tor HTTP proxy settings
[22:28:52] [CRITICAL] can't establish connection with the Tor proxy. Please make
 sure that you have Vidalia, Privoxy or Polipo bundle installed for you to be ab
le to successfully use switch '--tor' (e.g. https://www.torproject.org/projects/
vidalia.html.en)

[*] shutting down at 22:28:52
```

[CRITICAL] can't establish connection with the Tor proxy.
Vidalia Tor already instaled and runing.

How to use TOR with [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/)?

Comment: I find the way using fully description of tor key

sqlmap.py -u "http://host" --tor --tor-type=SOCKS5 --tor-port=9050

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always provide all of these: `--tor --check-tor --tor-type=SOCKS5 --tor-port=9150`
If you are using vidalia, then `--check-tor` isn't necessary but just to be sure you're using tor.
Let the good way rule

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the quotes `" "` for the url.
Try using `D:\path_to\sqlmap>sqlmap.py -u "www.mail.ru" --tor`

This post maybe useful for visitors, if not for you!! @Dmitrij Holkin

Answer (score 0):

What port is tor listening on? I think sqlmap uses 9050 as default. If yours is something other than that you can use --tor-port=TORPORT.